# Is there a good tool for programmatically creating diagrams?

Tags: diagram

I would like a tool to create diagram in a programming language, maybe something like lua.

Is there any tool designed for that?

Comment: I think you can make some pretty diagrams in latex
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149602/drawing-flow-diagram-in-latex-using-tikz

Comment: For simple diagrams you can use latex.
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149602/drawing-flow-diagram-in-latex-using-tikz

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can generate `.dot` files for [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Since these are text files, you can do it from any language. I wrote [a post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/23/visualizing-binary-trees-with-graphviz/) a while ago about auto-generating binary-tree diagrams from C code using Graphviz.

Comment: Yes, but .dot files don't let you move around the location of the elements. Right?

I was looking for more control of the position of boxes, arrows, etc.

Comment: @felipec: then, consider one of those SVG generating libraries

Answer (score 1):

A little retro, perhaps, but there's always [Pic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pic_language). It outputs to .eps which can easily be `convert`ed to anything you want.

The input is a little old-school, but since it's all-text, it can be targetted by any language (even Lua) that has text output. Here's an example of a diagram of a data-structure.

```
.PS
boxwid = .5; boxht = .25
down
Base: box "base"
Used: box "used"
Max: box "max"

move to Base.e
move right

right
Mfile: box dashed wid 3 ht 5
move to Mfile.nw; move down .125

Mtab: right; box "nexttab"; box "nextent"
move to Mtab.sw; move down .25

Tab: right; box "adr0"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr1"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr2"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr3"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr4"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr5"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr6"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr7"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adr8"; box "mark"; box "sz"
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box invis "..."; box invis "..."; box invis "..."
move to Tab.sw; move down .25
Tab: right; box "adrN"; box "mark"; box "sz"

arrow from Base.e to Mfile.nw
arrow from Used.e to Tab.sw down .125
arrow from Max.e to Mfile.sw

.PE
```

[image: Indexed-Memory Data Structure]